# Facebook/Mobile deep-linking + app links

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking, applinks

I'm confused.  I think I've fundamentally misunderstood how to use Open Graph stories + deep-linking across my iOS/Web app.  I'm hoping someone can help me clarify things.  Here's what I have:

- A web app set up that takes http://mywebapp.com/?video_id=XXXXXXXX
- Properly configured meta tags for app-links
- An iOS app with similar functionality that communicates with an API
- Facebook sharing on the iOS app.

Here's what I expect:

- See a link (ON MOBILE) in either the Facebook app or Safari, when I tap the link get the 'Install App' or 'Open in App' UX

I experimented with simply linking to 'http://mywebapp.com/?video_id=XXXXXXXX'.  It doesn't work UNLESS I go to the object debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and 'Fetch New Scrape Information' for that video_id (i.e. it doesn't work dynamically, the page has to be scraped.)  I also tried using Open Graph sharing with a contentURL and a combination of custom objects/actions/content/stories and at no stage did the Facebook app offer to open up the iOS app (again, unless I scraped the page in advance).

Have I misunderstood what is possible?  I take it that if I scrape + link to http://www.mywebapp.com it'll work fine, but I want to have custom stories like:

'User X played video 'Y' using MyWebApp', but that kind of dynamic sharing WITH a concept of deep linking/app link/whatever seems impossible.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: i think you are mixing a lot of things here. Can we break this down into what is working and what isnt ? there is not much clarity on that. 

For the open graph stories part (user X played video y), can you highlight what exactly is not working? or what have you tried ?